# Creating Polynomial Class Python Only

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, methods, static-methods

I've been working on a polynomial class that contains `def __mul__(self, other)`, `def __rmul__(self, other)` and `def derivative(self)` for quite some time but to no avail. Can someone please show me how it's done? Note that the lengths of the coefficients of self and other can be different. So far I have this:

```
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, coeffs):
        # if coeffs == [2,-3,5]:  2x**2-3*x+5
        self.coeffs = coeffs

    def almostEqual(d1, d2):
        epsilon = 0.000001
        return abs(d1 - d2) < epsilon

    def firstNonZeroCoeff(self, coeffs): 
        coeffs = self.coeffs
        for num in xrange(len(coeffs)): #loop through all coeffs
            if coeffs[num]!=0: #check if is 0
                return coeffs[num]

    def degree(self):
        return len(self.coeffs)-1

    def coeff(self, power):
        return self.coeffs[self.degree()-power]

    def evalAt(self, x):
        return sum([self.coeff(power)*x**power
                    for power in xrange(self.degree()+1)])

    def __add__(self, other):
        # First, made both coefficent lists the same length by nondestructively
        # adding 0's to the front of the shorter one
        (coeffs1, coeffs2) = (self.coeffs, other.coeffs)
        if (len(coeffs1) > len(coeffs2)):
            (coeffs1, coeffs2) = (coeffs2, coeffs1)
        # Now, coeffs1 is shorter, so add 0's to its front
        coeffs1 = [0]*(len(coeffs2)-len(coeffs1)) + coeffs1
        # Now they are the same length, so add them to get the new coefficients
        coeffs = [coeffs1[i] + coeffs2[i] for i in xrange(len(coeffs1))]
        # And create the new Polynomial instance with these new coefficients
        return Polynomial(coeffs)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of two polynomials will be a nested loop.  For each term in P1, you need to multiply the coefficient of it with the coefficients of all P2.  And then add all the intermediate results.   You may create intermediate polynomials just for multiplication's sake.  Then add them all together.

There is a nice worked example [here](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/polynomial/multiplying-polynomials-by-polynomials.php)

Make it work right first, then do any optimizations.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the prettiest implementation, but seems to work

```
def derivative(self):
    # Copy coefficeints to a new array
    der = list(self.coeffs)
    # (ax^n)' = (n)ax^(n-1)
    # 1. ax^n -> ax^(n-1)
    print der
    der.pop(0)
    print der
    # 2. ax^(n-1) -> (n)ax^(n-1)
    for n in range(1,self.degree()+1):
        der[n-1] *= n
    return Polynomial(der)
```